# Redirect de Javascript no sale del lopp de foreach php

Tags: php, javascript, condiciones, foreach, redirección

Buenas tardes estoy teniendo el siguiente problema bastante extraño. 
Tengo un `foreach` en php dentro del cual tengo varios `if` y dentro de cada if un `redirect` de javascript. 
El problema es el siguente al entrar en un if el `redirect` funciona y me envía a la pagina correcta pero también se ejecuta el código que estaba a continuación en la pagina original.

Revise la estructura tanto del `foreach` como de todos los `if` y parecen estar bien, así como correctamente cerrados.

No me exiplico como luego de redireccionar con `window.location.replace("../pagina/pagina.php?insc=existente&12");`igualmente se ejecuta el codigo que esta a continuación.

Alguna idea? 
Gracias

Comment: Si añades el código creo que será mas fácil ayudarte

Comment: Prueba colocando despues de la redirecion el comando break; de php para evitar que siga ejecutando el codigo

Comment: break o die cierra el ciclo